# Android Device Monitor Data Folder Only Containing "Con" Folders

Tags: android-sqlite, android-device-monitor

I'm trying to see my SqLiteDatabase by opening the Android Device Monitor. Im navigating to the right path, but the Data Folder is only containing this:

[image]

What do I need to fix/change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this problem. Your "Name" field is too short to display the full name of the folders. You need to resize it with your mouse!